# A continuous function taking natural numbers is constant

Tags: real-analysis

Let f:[0,1 ] to N  be a continuous function .Show that f is constant

We know that a continuous function on the given interval has Ivp then how to proceed? Please help

Comment: Suppose not.  Then .... ?

Comment: I am not being able to do it in that way